# Kotlin Exposed Unsolved Reference: referencedOn

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I'm trying to develop a REST API using `Ktor` framework and after going through some tutorials and the official documentation I just implemented a sample code. I'm also using Kotlin Exposed and I'm just trying to make some database tables and connect them.
So I made two classes `UsersRepo` and `RolesRepo` both extending `IntIdTable`. I just want to have a one to one relationship between these 2 tables so I did something like this:

```kotlin
object UsersRepo : IntIdTable("userId") {
    val displayName = varchar("display_name", 256)
    val role = reference("role", RolesRepo)
}
```

and then, I just wanted to implement the Entity class for the User and the IDE doesn't recognise the `referencedOn` keyword.[image]

I don't know what I'm missing here.
I'm using Ktor and Kotlin `1.4.0` and Kotlin Exposed version `0.25.1`

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:$exposed_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:$exposed_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposed_version"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you referenced the table instead of the entity for your role. It should be `var role by Role referencedOn UsersRepo.role`